# Tensorflow install from source: can't find resultant /tmp/tensorflow_pkg

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I've been going through the steps to install tensorflow from source (macOS, El Capitan), and I've successfully built a wheel file, it seems, but I can't find the folder that bazel is telling me it built it in (/tmp/tensorflow_pkg).

On building the package using the

```
$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
```

command I get this message:

```
~/tensorflow
Sun 6 May 2018 19:48:23 JST : === Output wheel file is in: /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
```

but I can't find the appropriate folder, and the site just says use the appropriate filename for your .whl file.

I am very new to all of this, and I'm not well versed in using the terminal at all.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Problem solved.  I didn't think to look into hidden files and folders.  After showing the hidden folders I found it right away.